# JJN Barclays iPath Bloomberg Nickel Subindex ETN , What happened in 2018 to its price?

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, commodities, etn

What happened to JJN price history? Barclays iPath Bloomberg Nickel Subindex Total Return ETN Series B

In January to March 2018? I am trying to understand its price history for analysis, don't see any news articles. This is a commodities ETN. It suddenly rose in 2018, dropped somewhat in March. Doesn't match the spot price at all.

[image: JJN Price History]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sudden drop like you see in March of 2018 is usually due to bad data.

The funky data before 1/18/18 is often caused for two reasons:

- There was a reverse split and the data provider didn't handle it properly
- There was a security with the same symbol prior to 1/18/18 and it  was delisted, perhaps due to bankruptcy or a merger.  The data provider then conjoined the two sets of data, resulting in that graph.

If you check JJN at Yahoo Finance or Marketwatch, the graphs are normal.